# Android - after publishing an app, how long before it is searchable?

Tags: android

I published my first app yesterday evening, and it appears under this url:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appname
```

but I can not find it from my mobile phone in the android market by any variations of the name?

Is there a reason for that?

Also, the name there is my project name in eclipse, but how do I change it so that the app has a normal looking name to users and doesn't have the com. in the com.appname ?

Thanks!!

ps - the app name is com.problemio

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.problemio"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ProblemioActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".AddProblemActivity"
            android:label="@string/add_problem" />

        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/login" />        

        <activity
            android:name=".MyProblemsActivity"
            android:label="@string/your_problems" /> 

        <activity
            android:name=".LogoutActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" /> 

        <activity
            android:name=".CreateProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/create_account" />         

        <activity
            android:name=".ProblemActivity"
            android:label="@string/problem_page_header" />   

        <activity
            android:name=".SuggestSolutionActivity"
            android:label="@string/suggest_solution_header" />  

        <activity
            android:name=".SuggestedSolutionActivity"
            android:label="@string/suggested_solution_header" />          

        <activity
            android:name=".ViewSolutionsActivity"
            android:label="@string/view_solutions_header" />        

        <activity
            android:name=".TopicActivity"
            android:label="@string/topic_header" /> 

    </application>

</manifest>
```

and I guess I need to add this line to it:

```
<supports-screens  android:largeScreens="true"   android:normalScreens="true"  android:smallScreens="true"/>
```

What else needs to be done? Thanks!

Comment: for this you need to post your manifest.xml here.

Comment: REQUIRES ANDROID:
and up its not showing any minsdk in google play. whats your app minimum API level required.

Comment: @PadmaKumar thanks, I just added the manifest file :)

Comment: your min sdk is android:minSdkVersion="15" only ICS device can find your app. so change it to 4.

Comment: @PadmaKumar Thank you - just changed it. So should I upload a new apk now and re-save the published app? How do I make it appear under the android market searches? :)

Comment: ya you need to upload new apk to market. do it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

//your minsdk is android:minSdkVersion="15" only Icream sandwitch (ICS) device can find your app from market.

if you are targeting for api level 15 you can also add `android:targetSdkVersion="15"`

so change it to api level 4. –

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Via you direct link using the package name, the App is available as soon as it is through Googles check routines and published in the Store.
But the search index takes more time to index the App. Usually it should be done in a few hours.

Comment: but he said he uploaded yesterday. how sure you are saying that its could be done in few hours?

Comment: According to the Play it was uploaded at March 28th. But there is also no Value for the min Android Version so i think there is something wrong with the Manifest too.

Comment: @Thommy yeah I uploaded the app a bit after midnight so it says the 28th :) I just added my manifest file to my original question. Does it clear up anything?  Thanks!